# pass in the class object itself in constructor

Tags: c#, generics, log4net

```
class LogUtil : ILogUtility
{
    object _classtype;
    log4net.ILog log;

    public LogUtil(object classtype)
    {
        _classtype = classtype;
        log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(_classtype.GetType().FullName);
    }

    public void Log(LogType logtype, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logging coming from class {0} - message {1} " , _classtype.GetType().FullName, message);
    }
}
```

From the client class code I call the above LogUtil class as follows:

```
public class TestCode
{

    public void test()
    {
        LogUtil logutil = new LogUtil(this);

    }

}
```

In the LogUtil constructor, I want to AVOID passing in **object** classtype. 
I want to pass in the client class object that I can pass to the GetLogger Method. GetLogger method needs to know which class instantiated the LogUtil class.

The way I have it now, I can pass in integer variable class type and it would work. I want to avoid it.

How do I do that? How can I utilize generics method in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
class LogUtil<T> : ILogUtility
{
    log4net.ILog log;

    public LogUtil()
    {
        log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T).FullName);
    }

    public void Log(LogType logtype, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logging coming from class {0} - message {1}", typeof(T).FullName, message);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
LogUtil<TestCode> logutil = new LogUtil<TestCode>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use method level generics, rather than class level generics (or rather, in addition to in this case), you can let type inference make things easier on you.

```
class LogUtil<T> : ILogUtility
{
    log4net.ILog log;

    public LogUtil<T>()
    {
        log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T));
    }

    public void Log(LogType logtype, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logging coming from class {0} - message {1} " , typeof(T).FullName, message);
    }

    public static LogUtil<NewType> Create<NewType>(NewType instance)
    {
      return new LogUtil<NewType>();
    }
}

public class TestCode
{
    public void test()
    {
        var logutil = LogUtil.Create(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd change it to this:

```
class LogUtility : ILogUtility
{
    private Type classType;
    public LogUtil(object o)
        : this(o.GetType())
    {
    }

    public LogUtil(Type t)
    {
        this.classType = t;
    }

    public static LogUtil Create<T>()
    {
        return new LogUtil(typeof(T));
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logging coming from class {0} - message {1} " , this.classType, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the LogUtil class as below.

```
class LogUtil : ILogUtility
{
    Type _classtype;
    log4net.ILog log;

    public LogUtil(Type classtype)
    {
        _classtype = classtype;
        log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(_classtype.FullName);
    }

    public void Log(LogType logtype, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logging coming from class {0} - message {1} " , _classtype.FullName, message);
    }
}
```

The client code should be as below,

```
public class TestCode
{

    public void test()
    {
        LogUtil logutil = new LogUtil(GetType());

    }

}
```

Comment: System.RuntimeType will be returned if I do _classtype.GetType().FullName... whereeas I want to be able to see ConsoleApplication1.TestCode